# eks cluster ALB Target binding webhook api error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

I have an private eks cluster and manually created ALB. i want to expose eks cluster service to ALB. I have created a target group and trying to bind service to that target group. But i am getting below error when i apply target binding yaml.

Below is the yaml file and the error

`apiVersion: elbv2.k8s.aws/v1beta1
kind: TargetGroupBinding
metadata:
name: tgb-eks
spec:

## targetType: instance

targetGroupARN: arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1::targetgroup/eks-tg/f750d87ad1c509ee
serviceRef:
name: test-app
port: 80`

The error is
`Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "target-group-binding.yml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "mtargetgroupbinding.elbv2.k8s.aws": failed to call webhook: Post "https://aws-load-balancer-webhook-service.kube-system.svc:443/mutate-elbv2-k8s-aws-v1beta1-targetgroupbinding?timeout=10s": context deadline exceeded`

I see see webhook service running file
`kube-system   service/aws-load-balancer-webhook-service   ClusterIP   172.20.195.253   <none>        443/TCP                  2d1h`

Comment: You need to provide more details to help. You should provide namespace, service deployment and details if your alb load balancer controller in kube-system namespace is up and running. Context deadline could mean a network timeout or it could be if your alb lb controller is failing. Also provide version of your kubernetes cluster as well as ALB controller.

Answer (score 0):

I meet the same problem. but the answer from google tell me to add security group rule to allow k8s control plane to access node plane on port `9443`, maybe it works for you, but it doesn't work for me. the issue in github. https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-load-balancer-controller/issues/2039

Comment: the question lacks granular details for an answer. Also for the solution provided, the answer is not suitable.